# ubuntu - node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(403): https://node-zopfli.s3.amazonaws.com/Release/zopfli-v1.4.0-node-v48-linux-x64.tar.gz

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, mean-stack, angular-fullstack

System information:

AWS EC2 Ubuntu 16.04 
node v.6.10.2
npm 3.10.10

using angular-fullstack-generator

when try:

```
gulp serve
```

get this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/home/ubuntu/projects/mean-test-v5/node_modules/node-zopfli/lib/binding/node-v48-linux-x64/zopfli.node'
```

So i run:

```
npm rebuild
```

And received this error:

```
node-zopfli@1.4.0 install /home/ubuntu/projects/mean-test-v5/node_modules/node-zopfli
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(403): https://node-zopfli.s3.amazonaws.com/Release/zopfli-v1.4.0-node-v48-linux-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for node-zopfli@1.4.0 and node@6.10.2 (node-v48 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "/path/to/executable/python2.7", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:449:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:353:11
gyp ERR! stack     at F (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:69:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at E (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:81:29)
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:90:16
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/node_modules/isexe/index.js:44:5
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/node_modules/isexe/access.js:8:5
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-72-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/home/ubuntu/projects/mean-test-v5/node_modules/node-zopfli/lib/binding/node-v48-linux-x64/zopfli.node" "--module_name=zopfli" "--module_path=/home/ubuntu/projects/mean-test-v5/node_modules/node-zopfli/lib/binding/node-v48-linux-x64" "--python=/path/to/executable/python2.7" "--msvs_version=2015"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/ubuntu/projects/mean-test-v5/node_modules/node-zopfli
gyp ERR! node -v v6.10.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/bin/nodejs
```

Comment: _"Can't find Python executable..."_ is probably the main cause of your issue, so make sure Python 2.7 is installed.

Comment: Python 2.7 is installed. i double checked

Comment: Try explicitly configuring its path: `npm config set python /path/to/executable/python` (and make sure you replace `/path/to/executable/python` with the _actual_ path of the Python executable, not that string verbatim)